# Autosend email invitation via APIs in SurveyMonkey

Tags: api, surveymonkey

I have a feedback survey form need to send out daily when i received a new list of recipients.
Is it possible we can schedule a particular survey email invitations to be send out daily/weekly at certain time (e.g. midnight 12AM) with the new contacts list (will be different, or same email address may repeat) each day. At the same time, i still want to keep track the old recipients responses/bounced messages each time/in total. Or what is the best approach?

I m planning to update the same email invitation recipients list(Collectors) thru API with a pre-create recipients list.

Here are some findings from SUrveyMonkey APIs doc site:
- contacts_write: to Create/Modify Contacts
- collectors_write: to Create/Modify Collectors 
- /collectors/{id}/messages/{id}/recipients/bulk
- /collectors/{COLLECTOR_ID}/messages/{MESSAGE_ID}/send

Any better approaches can share with me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the two endpoints you specified would be the way to go. There's a number of ways to do this. One way is to have a script run on a [cron job](https://cron-job.org/en/).

Something like `00 00 * * * ./your_script`.

Then make sure your script pulls the recipients you want to send to from whatever data source you have for that and then call SurveyMonkey's API to:

1) [Create a new message](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages) on the collector

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages
{
    "type": "invite"
}
```

2) [Insert all the recipients](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-recipients-bulk) you pulled into the message

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages/<message_id>/recipients/bulk
{
    "contacts": [{
        "email": "test@example.com",
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Example"
    }...]
}
```

3) Then [send out the message](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-send) immediately

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/messages/<message_id>/send
{}
```

That's one way to have a scheduled task run, using the SurveyMonkey API.